# What anime are these keychains from?

Tags: merchandise

I really would like to know what this is from if possible? But I might be buying them and I want to know what I'm getting.

[image: keychains]

Comment: where did you get that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blue one is [**Aki Hasumi**](https://vndb.org/c37666) from the otoge visual novel for PS Vita called [**Root∞REXX**](https://vndb.org/v15577).
[Link to item](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%88%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88-ROOT%E2%88%9EREXX-%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9-%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8A%E3%82%80%E3%81%8D%E3%82%85%E3%82%93%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9B%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC-%E8%93%AE%E6%B0%B4%E7%A7%8B%EF%BC%88%E5%8D%98%E5%93%81%EF%BC%89/dp/B01A6UZCWY)

The red one is [**Kiriya Etou**](https://myanimelist.net/character/19329/Kiriya_Etou) from the [**Kiniro no Corda**](https://myanimelist.net/manga/1051/Kiniro_no_Corda) anime and manga series.
[Link to item](https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/n172878590)

Comment: Upvoted for providing links to product pages as evidence.